# Git path to match any directory name

Tags: git, glob

In  git we can use `*` to specify files name, like `*.jpg`, `*.*`, but how about directories?

Is there any method to specify all directory?

This doesn't work:

```
git rm firstdirectory/*/thirddirectory
```

The `*` doesn't do the "all directories" effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your command doesn't work because you're specifying a directory to git. Your shell does  the correct expansion, but in the end git receives `git rm firstdirectory/somedir/thirddirectory`, which git doesn't like (`git rm` expects files)

To make your command work, use the `-r` flag, then git accepts directory:

```
git rm -r firstdirectory/*/thirddirectory
```

Answer (score 0):

The glob expression expansion you describe is not performed by git but by the shell. You can see this if you do something like `echo *`. The command receives a list of arguments which are filenames - not a single argument with an asterisk.

In your case, `find . -ipath` is probably the most useful way to identify the paths you need. You may want to add a `-type d` to just fetch directories. find has a number of options for selecting matching objects. You can then feed this into `xargs` to work with `git`. For example:

```
find firstdirectory -ipath 'firstdirectory/*/thirddirectory' | xargs git rm
```